# fsspec - is there a way how we can get paginated response from sftp?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, fsspec

I use fsspec which uses in-built capabilities of paramiko but could not really find a way how we can paginate the response.

Is there a way to have that functionality over here?

The use-case is like every directory has 100000 files and listing all of these separately in memory is a bad-idea I suppose.

There is a sftp.listdir_iter but do we have that capability in fsspec?

Comment: As alternative you can use [`walk`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem.walk) from `fsspec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`listdir_iter`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_iter) would provide a more direct way to achieve pagination since it returns an iterator, allowing you to retrieve items one by one.

```py
import paramiko
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem

class PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def listdir_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0):
        if not self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        sftp = self.ftp

        # Use Paramiko's listdir_iter method
        items_iter = sftp.listdir_iter(path)

        # Skip the items before the starting page
        for _ in range(start_page * page_size):
            try:
                next(items_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                break

        items = []
        for i, item in enumerate(items_iter):
            if i >= page_size:
                break
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

---

But you could also consider [`listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr), which loads all items at once and then slices the list to get the desired page: that would be faster.
That mean you can try and implement the pagination by slicing the returned list of [`SFTPAttributes`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_attr.SFTPAttributes) objects. For example:

```py
import paramiko
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem

class PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def listdir_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0):
        if not self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        sftp = self.ftp

        # Use Paramiko's listdir_attr method
        items = sftp.listdir_attr(path)

        # Slice the items list to implement pagination
        start_index = start_page * page_size
        end_index = start_index + page_size
        paginated_items = items[start_index:end_index]

        # Extract filenames from the SFTPAttributes objects
        filenames = [item.filename for item in paginated_items]

        return filenames
```

You would use it as:

```py
fs = PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password")
paginated_response = fs.listdir_paginated("/path/to/your/directory", page_size=1000, start_page=0)
```

This approach is slightly more efficient than the one using [`listdir_iter`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_iter), since it avoids iterating through the items one by one.
However, it still loads *all* the `SFTPAttributes` objects in memory before slicing the list. This memory overhead might not be an issue unless you have a very large number of files and limited memory resources.

---

To use `listdir_iter` with [fsspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can create a custom `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` class that inherits from [`SFTPFileSystem`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.sftp.SFTPFileSystem).
The custom class accesses the underlying paramiko SFTP client through the `self.ftp` attribute, and then would still use the `listdir_iter` method directly.

```py
import paramiko
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem

class PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def listdir_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0):
        if not self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        sftp = self.ftp  # Access the paramiko SFTP client

        # Use Paramiko's listdir_iter method
        items_iter = sftp.listdir_iter(path)

        # Implement pagination by controlling the iterator
        # ... (rest of the implementation)

        return items
```

By accessing the `paramiko` SFTP client in this way, you can use `listdir_iter` to implement pagination directly, even though it is not part of `fsspec`.

---

Using [`sshfs`](https://github.com/fsspec/sshfs) (an implementation of fsspec for the SFTP protocol using [asyncssh](https://github.com/ronf/asyncssh)), I do not see a `SSHFS.listdir`-like method.

But `sshfs` also [has a lot of other basic filesystem operations, such as `mkdir`, `touch` and `find`](https://github.com/fsspec/sshfs/blob/a62fd30cfcf55ef74345a0cc398f5779a1577ffa/README.md?plain=1#L76).

You might therefore try and use the [`find` method, which is inherited from the `AbstractFileSystem` class in `fsspec`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem.find), for pagination:

```py
import sshfs

class PaginatedSSHFS(sshfs.SSHFS):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def find_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0):
        if not await self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        # Use SSHFS's find method
        items = await super().find(path, detail=False)

        # Implement pagination by slicing the items list
        start_index = start_page * page_size
        end_index = start_index + page_size
        paginated_items = items[start_index:end_index]

        return paginated_items
```

You can use this custom implementation in your project as follows:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    fs = PaginatedSSHFS(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password")
    paginated_response = await fs.find_paginated("/path/to/your/directory", page_size=1000, start_page=0)
    print(paginated_response)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This implementation uses the `find` method with the detail parameter set to `False` to get a list of file paths.
Then, it implements pagination by slicing the list of items.

Again, this approach loads *all* the items into memory before slicing the list, which may be inefficient for very large directories.

---

> Do you know if there's a way how we can add an sftp connection directly to the `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` instead of having `host`, `username`, `password` again since I already have a `fsspec.filesystem` object sftp connection created that performs multiple tasks?

I suppose you can pass an existing `SFTPFileSystem` object to your custom `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` class and use its underlying sftp connection.

To do this, you can modify the custom class to accept an `SFTPFileSystem` object during initialization and use its `sftp` attribute for listing the directory items.

```py
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem

class PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def __init__(self, sftp_fs, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sftp = sftp_fs.ftp
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def listdir_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0):
        if not self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        # Use the sftp connection from the existing SFTPFileSystem object
        items_iter = self.sftp.listdir_iter(path)

        # Implement pagination by controlling the iterator
        # ... (rest of the implementation)

        return items
```

Now you can create an `SFTPFileSystem` object and pass it to the `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem`:

```py
sftp_fs = SFTPFileSystem(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password")

# Pass the existing SFTPFileSystem object to the custom PaginatedSFTPFileSystem
paginated_fs = PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(sftp_fs)

paginated_response = paginated_fs.listdir_paginated("/path/to/your/directory", page_size=1000, start_page=0)
print(paginated_response)
```

This custom class will now use the sftp connection from the *existing* `SFTPFileSystem` object, eliminating the need to provide the `host`, `username`, and `password` again.

---

[Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233635/fsspec-is-there-a-way-how-we-can-get-paginated-response-from-sftp/76248567#comment134462262_76233635) to use [`walk(path, maxdepth=None, topdown=True, **kwargs)`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem.walk).

You can use this method with your custom `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` class, as it inherits from `SFTPFileSystem`, which in turn inherits from `AbstractFileSystem`.
This means that the `walk` method is available to your custom class.

However, that might not be the most suitable choice for pagination, as it returns files and directories in a nested structure, making it harder to paginate the results in a straightforward manner.

If you need pagination for only the top-level directories, you can modify the custom `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` class to include a custom implementation of the walk method with pagination support for the top level.

```py
from fsspec.implementations.sftp import SFTPFileSystem

class PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(SFTPFileSystem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def walk_paginated(self, path, page_size=1000, start_page=0, maxdepth=None, topdown=True, **kwargs):
        if not self.isdir(path):
            raise ValueError("Path should be a directory")

        # Use the original walk method to generate the nested structure
        walk_generator = super().walk(path, maxdepth=maxdepth, topdown=topdown, **kwargs)

        # Implement pagination for the top level only
        start_index = start_page * page_size
        end_index = start_index + page_size

        paginated_walk = []
        for idx, (root, directories, files) in enumerate(walk_generator):
            if start_index <= idx < end_index:
                paginated_walk.append((root, directories, files))
            if idx >= end_index:
                break

        return paginated_walk
```

Used with:

```py
fs = PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password")

paginated_response = fs.walk_paginated("/path/to/your/directory", page_size=1000, start_page=0)
for root, directories, files in paginated_response:
    print(f"Root: {root}")
    print(f"Directories: {directories}")
    print(f"Files: {files}\n")
```

Again, that would only paginates the *top-level* directories and files, not those within the subdirectories.
If you need pagination for files and directories at all levels, consider using the `find` method or the custom `listdir_paginated` method, as shown in previous examples.

---

As noted by [mdurant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821154/mdurant) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233635/fsspec-is-there-a-way-how-we-can-get-paginated-response-from-sftp/76248567#comment134464747_76248567):

> **fsspec caches filesystem instances**, so if you call SSHFileSystem (or derivative) withe same arguments twice, you do NOT create a new ftp session but reuse the existing one.

See [Instance/Listing caching](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#instance-caching).

Depending on your use-case, you might need to pass `skip_instance_cache=True` or `use_listings_cache=False`.

Consider that, if you use the same arguments to create a PaginatedSFTPFileSystem instance, fsspec will return the cached SFTPFileSystem instance.
If you want to force the creation of a new FTP session, you can do so by passing a unique argument when creating the `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem` instance.

For example, you can add a dummy argument that takes a unique value each time you want to create a new FTP session:

```py
# Create a new PaginatedSFTPFileSystem instance with a new FTP session
fs1 = PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password", dummy_arg1="unique_value_1")

# Create another new PaginatedSFTPFileSystem instance with a new FTP session
fs2 = PaginatedSFTPFileSystem(host="your_host", username="your_username", password="your_password", dummy_arg2="unique_value_2")
```

In that example, `fs1` and `fs2` will have separate FTP sessions, despite having the same host, username, and password, because the unique dummy arguments force `fsspec` to create new instances instead of reusing the cached one.

Comment: ``` 
        items_iter = sftp.listdir_iter(path)
```

there is no declaration for listdir_iter in fsspec I see.

Comment: I think this is suggesting subclassing the fsspec implementation. That would be fine, or this could be upstreamed (I would accept it), but you should also look into https://github.com/fsspec/sshfs

Comment: @LearnerJS I thought that, since fsspec uses paramiko under the hood for SFTP, you can access the underlying paramiko SFTP client to use the `listdir_iter` method.

Comment: @VonC It's a good approach tho, thanks. Do you know if there's a way how we can add an sftp connection directly to the PaginatedSFTPFileSystem instead of having host, username, password again since I already have a fsspec.filesystem object sftp connection created that performs multiple tasks?

Comment: @LearnerJS I have added the SSHFS approach.

Comment: No, that'd actually be again inefficient since memory comes into picture, atleast for my use-case but thanks for the ellaborate explanation.

Comment: @LearnerJS I agree. I was just echoing [mdurant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233635/fsspec-is-there-a-way-how-we-can-get-paginated-response-from-sftp/76248567#comment134461635_76248567)

Comment: @LearnerJS I have added the approach for passing an existing `SFTPFileSystem` object to your custom `PaginatedSFTPFileSystem`.

Comment: Accepted, will reward the bounty after 14 hours.

Comment: Quick note: fsspec caches filesystem instances, so if you call SSHFileSystem (or derivative) withe same arguments twice, you do NOT create a new ftp session but reuse the existing one.